# Opening a file in Python

Tags: python, file

I use the following function for opening files in Python:

```
def file_path(relative_path):
    folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    path_parts = relative_path.split("/")
    new_path = os.path.join(folder, *path_parts)
    return new_path
```

I call it with a relative path, like this:

```
with open(file_path("my_files/zen_of_python.txt")) as f:
    zop = f.read()
```

I like it because you can use a relative path works no matter where the Python script is executed from:

1. `folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` gets the
   absolute path to the folder holding the python script.
2. `os.path.join(folder, *path_parts)` gets an os-independent path to the file to open.

To further explain, let's say I have the following folder structure:

> ```
> - parent_folder
>   - example.py
>   - my_files
>     - zen_of_python.txt
> ```

If example.py looks like this:

```
with open("my_files/zen_of_python.txt") as f:
    zop = f.read()
```

Then I have to run example.py from the parent_folder directory or else it won't find `my_files/zen_of_python.txt`.

But if I open `my_files/zen_of_python.txt` using the `file_path()` function shown above, I can run example.py from anywhere.

One downside as @infinitezero pointed out is that you can't use an absolute path, but for my purposes, that's okay for my purposes. The script is self-contained. I'm not passing in external files when I run it.

Can anyone see any downside to this? Or does anyone have a more Pythonic way of accomplishing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

Your code represents a well-known pattern. In Java, files like this are called *resource files* and they are delivered together with the code in a .jar file (which is essentially a .zip file).

As pointed out in a comment, you cannot use your code with absolute paths. This is good since the entire purpose of the code is to find a resource *relative* to the source code that needs this resource.

The call to `abspath` looks redundant to me. I'm assuming that `__file__` is already an absolute path. You may want to check the documentation about it.

A downside of your function is that you have to define it in each file that wants to open relative files since it uses `__file__`. You cannot `import` that function, as it is now.

Comment: If you execute a script using a relative path (e.g., `python my_file.py`), then `__file__` will be relative. You're right that a downside is that you cannot import the function unless it's in the same directory. You could fix this by accepting  `__file__` as a 2nd param.

Answer (score 1):

If using just `os.path`, this looks almost perfect.

- Move `folder` into the global scope, as there's no point not to. It means that the function can be made simpler - as it's now split into two seperate entities.

```py
FOLDER = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


def file_path(relative_path):
    return os.path.join(folder, *relative_path.split("/"))
```

---

It would be better if you used `pathlib`. This is the modern version of `os.path`. If you do, then I would recomend just making `folder` as there would be no need for the function.

```py
FOLDER = pathlib.Path(__file__).resolve().parent

with (FOLDER / 'my_files/zen_of_python.txt').open() as f:
    ...
```

Here are some examples of running it on Windows in Python 3.8.

```py
>>> import pathlib
>>> FOLDER = pathlib.Path('foo')
>>> FOLDER / 'bar/baz'  # Unix style
WindowsPath('foo/bar/baz')
>>> FOLDER / 'bar\\baz'  # Windows style
WindowsPath('foo/bar/baz')
>>> FOLDER / 'bar' / 'baz'  # Pathlib style
WindowsPath('foo/bar/baz')
```